# How to calculate the period of non-circular orbits?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity

How to calculate the period of non-circular [orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period)?

By conservation of mechanical energy:
$$
E = -\frac{GMm}{r} + \frac{1}{2}\mu \left ( \dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\theta}^2 \right )
$$
By the [conservation of angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum):
$$
L = \mu r^2 \dot{\theta} \; \; \Rightarrow \; \; \dot{\theta} = \frac{L}{\mu r^2}
$$
Hence:
$$
E = -\frac{GMm}{r} + \frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2} + \frac{\mu}{2}\left( \frac{dr}{dt} \right)^2
$$
Rearranging a little bit:
$$
\int_{r_{max}}^{r_{min}} \frac{\pm \mu r}{\sqrt{2\mu E r^2 + 2GMm\mu r - L^2}}\; dr = \int_0^{T/2}dt
$$
$$
T = \int_{r_{max}}^{r_{min}} \frac{\pm 2 \mu r}{\sqrt{2\mu E r^2 + 2GMm\mu r - L^2}}\; dr
$$

The limits of integration of the radial integral, go from $r_{max}$ to $r_{min}$. This would take $T/2$ seconds. That's why the limits of integration for $t$, range from $0$ to $T/2$.

My question is:  I have chosen the limits of $r$ arbitrarily. But why I can't choose $r_{min}$ first and then $r_{max}$?

When I've tried to plug this integral into a software program, it failed. I saw that it was because of my choice of, $r_{min}$, it would not enter into the domain of:

$$
\frac{\mu r}{\sqrt{2\mu E r^2 + 2GMm\mu r - L^2}}
$$

So, the integral would be undefined.

Why does this happen? It should work, no?

Do I miss something? Is this integral even right?

Comment: If you are not sure if your period is right you can cross check it with the equation found all over the internet called Kepler's 3rd law T=2π√[a³/G/(M+m)] where a is the semimajor axis. If you integrate the other way around you have to change the + and -, escpecially if √ are involved

Comment: What about here: @ https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-derive-the-period-of-non-circular-orbits.1054817/  ?

Comment: Your value of $r_\min$ must have been too low. Have you considered picking $r_\min,\,r_\max$ as the roots of the $\sqrt{}$'s argument? Note $\int_{r_\min}^{r_\max}\frac{rdr}{\sqrt{(r-r_\min)(r_\max-r)}}$ is an easily computed convergent integral, with $r=r_\min+(r_\max-r_\min)\sin^2u$.

Comment: Your choice of sign for $\frac{dr}{dt}$ will determine whether the integral runs from $r_{min}$ to $r_{max}$ or vice versa. The integrand in your expression for $T$ appears to have the wrong sign based on the limits of integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't go through all the algebra of the mentioned equations, I will just provide some basic information.

First of all $r_{min}$ and $r_{max}$ should be determined. As $r$ is a radial variable is should only adapt positive values. However, as the motion of the particle is bound, the total energy $E$ will adapt a negative value.

The turning point are defined by a change of sign of the derivative $\frac{dr}{dt}$, i.e. at the turning points $\frac{dr}{dt}=0$. Then we obtain an quadratical equation whose solutions provide as with $r_{min}$ and $r_{max}$.

The quadratical equation has the following form:

$$E = -\frac{A}{r} +\frac{B}{r^2}$$

where we abreviated $A= GMm$ and $B=0.5L^2/\mu$. Furthermore we will use $F=-E=|E|$ with $F>0$. Then we get:

$$ r^2 -\frac{A}{F}r + \frac{B}{F} =0 $$

whose solutions are( we assume here that $(GMm)^2 > 2L^2F/\mu \equiv 2L^2|E|/\mu$):

$$r_{min} = \frac{A}{2F} -\sqrt{(\frac{A}{2F})^2 - \frac{B}{F}}>0$$

and
$$r_{max} = \frac{A}{2F} +\sqrt{(\frac{A}{2F})^2 - \frac{B}{F}}>r_{min}>0$$

Both values should be inserted as integration borders. And replace in the integral $+E$ by $-F$ remembering that $F>0$. With this hint you should be able to carry out the integration.

By the way: the integration borders should be set like $\int_{r_{min}}^{r_{max}}$. The time span on the rhs is positive and the integral of the lhs too and of course it is the same independent on if the particle moves from  $r_{min}$ to $r_{max}$ or from $r_{max}$ to $r_{min}$.